# How to conditionally duplicate and edit rows in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to add 2 rows to a dataframe that have the same values as existing rows. For example, below I would need to add "a" = 3 with the same "b" values as "a" = 2, going from this:

```
| a | b     |
| --| ------|
| 1 | higha |
| 1 | lowa  |
| 2 | highb |
| 2 | lowb  |
```

to this:

```
| a | b     |
| --| ------|
| 1 | higha |
| 1 | lowa  |
| 2 | highb |
| 2 | lowb  |
| 3 | highb |
| 3 | lowb  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   uncount((a == 2)+1) %>%
   mutate(a = replace(a, duplicated(b) & a == 2, 3)) %>%
   arrange(a)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
      a b    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 higha
2     1 lowa 
3     2 highb
4     2 lowb 
5     3 highb
6     3 lowb
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
i1 <- df$a == 2
df[nrow(df) + seq_len(sum(i1)),] <- data.frame(a = 3, b = df$b[i1])
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = rep(1:2, each = 2), 
   b = c("higha", "lowa", "highb", "lowb"))
```

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner in base R would be:

```r
`rownames<-`(rbind(df, within(df[df$a == 2,], a <- 3)), NULL)
#>   a     b
#> 1 1 higha
#> 2 1  lowa
#> 3 2 highb
#> 4 2  lowb
#> 5 3 highb
#> 6 3  lowb
```